# convert two Pandas columns into yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS

Tags: pandas, formatting, python-datetime

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like:

```
   YYYYMMDD  HH
0  19900101   1
1  19900101   2
2  19900101   3
3  19900101   4
4  19900101   5
```

With 
YYYYMMDD: year-month-day values as integers. 
HH: hourly values as integers.

I want to get a column 'DateTime' which is a datetime column as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss. (so, mm:ss=00:00).

```
df['DateTime'] = df['YYYYMMDD'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x), format='%Y%m%d'))
```

Gives me yyyy-mm-dd as datetime, is there a fancy way to add 'HH' values to the datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
    df['Datetime'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['YYYYMMDD'],format='%Y%m%d')
                        .add(pd.to_timedelta(df['HH'], 'h')))
print(df)
   YYYYMMDD  HH            Datetime
0  19900101   1 1990-01-01 01:00:00
1  19900101   2 1990-01-01 02:00:00
2  19900101   3 1990-01-01 03:00:00
3  19900101   4 1990-01-01 04:00:00
4  19900101   5 1990-01-01 05:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['DateTime'] = df['YYYYMMDD'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x), format='%Y%m%d')) + (pd.to_timedelta(df.HH, unit='H'))
```

Solved it.